# What is the best way to do custom sort?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

```
arr = ["h12020", "h22018", "h22020", "h22019", "h12019"]

expected_arr = ["h22018","h12019","h22019","h12020", "h22020"]
```

**The way I tried:**

```
arr.sort { |a, b| a.slice(2, 4) <=> b.slice(2, 4) } # ["h22018","h22019","h12019","h12020", "h22020"]
```

What is the way to sort `arr` to get `expected_arr` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just small syntax differences with other answers, a little bit cleaner:

```rb
arr.sort_by { |a| a[2..5] + a[1] } # Ruby
arr.sort_by { |a| a.last(4) + a[1] } # Rails
```

Comment: No reason to use `slice`, indeed. Spending too much time with JavaScript lately. :) Ruby's ranges are something that JavaScript could seriously use.

Answer (score 3):

Using `#sort_by` is usually more concise, as it is here:

```
arr.sort_by {|a| a.slice(2, 4) + a.slice(1, 1)} 
# ["h22018", "h12019", "h22019", "h12020", "h22020"]
```

Also, you can manipulate the string inside the block to put it in the order that you want. Here, I've just sliced the number you're sorting by and tacked it on the end. You can also use ranges as nuaky has done.

Using `#sort` with a block is more flexible, in particular for things like descending order. But it is less concise and doesn't typically perform as well in situations where you can use `#sort_by`.

Comment: Performance depends on the use case. The docs say that [`sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#sort_by-method) is _"fairly expensive when the keysets are simple."_

Comment: @Stefan I agree with your first sentence. About the second sentence, the doc is comparing the `#sort` method with no block given. Based on the limited benchmarks I have done on comparing the two, `#sort_by` (typically, tends to, insert favorite weasel word here) performs better than doing the same thing with `#sort` and a spaceship operator. Matz says this in his book: "If the block you associate with sort must do substantial computation in order to perform its comparison, then it is more efficient to use sort_by." So, as you say, performance depends on use case.

Answer (score 2):

You can split each value `[a[2..5], a[1..1]]` => `["2020", "1"]` and then sort by year and first number:

```
arr.sort_by { |a| [a[2..5], a[1..1]] }
```

this will sort by year (2020, 2019) and then by other param (1, 2), so you will get:

```
["h22018", "h12019", "h22019", "h12020", "h22020"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Less readable and less efficient, but way cooler:

```
arr.sort_by { _1.chars.rotate(2) }
```